# What does the + mean on Mac Dev Center?

Tags: objective-c

For example, [NSString documentation has](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
– initWithFormat:
– initWithFormat:arguments:
– initWithFormat:locale:
– initWithFormat:locale:arguments:
– initWithData:encoding:
+ stringWithFormat:
+ localizedStringWithFormat:
+ stringWithCharacters:length:
+ stringWithString:
+ stringWithCString:encoding:
+ stringWithUTF8String:
```

So what does it mean when a method name has a + at its left?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406667/objective-c-clarification-and-var

Comment: No it isn't.  This question refers strictly to browsing the online documentation, not __writing code__ as the other question does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

method with + is a static method. so you will send message to class, not to it's instance.

Answer (score 7):

`+` is for class methods (aka `static` methods in languages like C# and Java) - methods which relate to the type rather than a specific instance of the type.

`-` is for instance methods; methods which are called on a particular instance.

So for example, we have

```
- length
+ availableStringEncodings
```

because `length` refers to the length of a specific string, whereas `availableStringEncodings` just returns a list of the encodings available on the system.

This is just part of Objective-C - I suggest you find a good Objective-C book or tutorial.

Comment: A more complete answer!  But the first answer was submitted first.  I've never been so torn in my life :S

Comment: Actually I think my answer was just about submitted first, but it really doesn't matter :)