# Objective-C static method problem

Tags: objective-c

I have a static method that should take two objects and a float as parameters. Everything is fine with the objects, but my float variable is lost. Here is a test case:

```
+ (void) someFunctionWithSomething: (xmlNodePtr *) node {
    CGFloat fsize = 0;
    if (fsize == 0) {
    fsize = 15.0f;
    }

    NSLog (@"size1: %f", fsize);    // output is 15.00000
    [MyClass getFontWithSize: fsize];
}

+ (void) getFontWithSize: (CGFloat) fsize {

    NSLog (@"size2: %f", fsize);    // output is 0.00000
}
```

How come my variable becomes zero all of a sudden? Could this be related to the fact that I am calling a static method from within a static method? I have a feeling that this is something really simple that I am missing here. Ideas?

Comment: Is this the actual code that causes the errors? Because you say that you have a method that takes two objects and a float, but you provide a method which takes one object and no float.

Comment: I think you might want to have a read of the existing [Objective-C Clarification; -/+ and *var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406667/objective-c-clarification-and-var) question as well. :-)

Comment: @Philipp Jaquet, that is irrelevant, as I mention in the question that this code reproduces the problem. Anyway, I have my answer already.

Comment: @Shade: No, it's not - and no, it doesn't. I tried to reproduce your error and couldn't, because your code itself works, if integrated correctly (i.e. with the method signature in the .h file).

Comment: A point about terminology: these are not static methods, they are class methods.

Comment: @JeremyP, thank you for the remark :) I am quite new to objective-c and some areas are a bit foggy at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your header file has a prototype for `getFontWithSize` that also matches your definition:

```
 +(void) getFontWithSize: (CGFloat) fsize;
```

Maybe you have something different there.

Comment: thanks, that was it. I didn't know that skipping the header definition can have such disastrous consequences. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @Shade: that warning you were previously ignoring that said "methods with an undefined signature are assumed to return id and take ... as arguments"? That's important: it means that the code is going to look at a pointer register (rather than a floating-point register) for its input, and interpret it as a pointer.

Comment: @Graham Lee, I see. The thing is that I am a beginner with Obj-C and am working with a very large project (185 classes) that has over 500 compilation warnings. Most of the code is not mine and I have stopped paying attention to warnings.

Comment: @Shade: no prob! Glad it helped. It's not an objetiveC specific problem. I think the same will happen in good old plain **C**. **C++** is more strict about these kind of things...