# method may not respond to

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Inside a class (named TimeDetails), I need to call a method (a class method) but during the compilation I receive this message: TimesDetails may not respond to 'generateTimeOfPassage' , (one method call another and send a NSString object. (In this case return nil).

in the .h file I declare the method like this:

```
+(NSString *)generateTimeOfPassage:(NSString *)_timeString;
```

in the .m file :

```
-(void)initWithTimeData:(NSString *)_timeString{
    [super init];
    passage=[self generateTimeOfPassage:_timeString]; ---I have the message here...
}
+(NSString *)generateTimeOfPassage:(NSString *)_timeString{

    return nil;
}
```

Thanks !

Maxime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's a `+` in front of it, then it's a class method (in Java, this would be called a static method). When there's a `-`, it's an instance method. [See here for further explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406667/objective-c-clarification-and-var)

Answer (score 6):

+generateTimeOfPassage is a class method, so it should be called using class name, not an object:

```
passage=[TimeDetails generateTimeOfPassage:_timeString];
```

Comment: Or [[self class] generateTimeOfPassage:_timeString] if subclasses are allowed to override the method.