# is it bad practice the static methods/function?

Tags: c#, static-methods

Is that a bad practice to implement static function/method which only doing some arithmetic (+, -, *, /) operations or comparisons (<, <=, =>, >, !=, ==)?

For example,

```
public class Clazzy {
 public static bool SecondRangelsPartsOfTheFirst(Datum rangeABegin, Datum rangeAEnd, Datum 
   rangeBBegin, Datum rangeBEnd)
 {
    return (rangeABegin<= rangeBBegin) && (rangeBEnd <= rangeAEnd);
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether something is "bad" or "good" practice is totally up to you, and how you decide to architect your code.

Comment: Dosis solum facit venenum. If your whole program is static functions and structs, then C# may not have been the best of language choices. But making functions static where it makes sense is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bad practice to make your `SecondRangelsPartsOfTheFirst()` method static. On the contrary, you *should* make the method static since it doesn't involve any instance members. Some static analysis tools like *MS Code Analysis* even encourages to use static methods and using static methods can have a performance gain.

When CA1822 rule is issued, Visual Studio gives this message in the Error List pane:

> Members that do not access instance data or call instance methods can
> be marked as static. After you mark the methods as static, the
> compiler will emit nonvirtual call sites to these members. This can
> give you a measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code.

Have a look at [CA1822: Mark members as static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1822).

Answer (score 1):

"Static methods are usually useful for operations that don't require any data from an instance of the class (from this) and can perform their intended purpose solely using their arguments."

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202560/when-should-i-write-static-methods#:%7E:text=You%20may%20use%20static%20methods,class%20exist%20in%20the%20system.)